Error Displaying Toast using the native SnackBar. Is Snackbar Deprecated
I tried showing a toast using the Snackbar but I am getting this error:
The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'ScaffoldState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'
  //Show toaster
  showToast(){
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Sending Message"),
    ));
  }


Does showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext' answer your question?

It's ScaffoldMessenger not Scaffold:
const snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
);

// Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
// and use it to show a SnackBar.

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

